# rtabmap with stereovision

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i work on rtabmap with stereovision. i am new in ros and rtabmap and i am studying tutorials of rtabmap. i install rtabmap_ros package from ($ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rtabmap-ros) and when run the  example of
Hand-held Stereo Mapping for ros (Process a directory of stereo images in ROS) the stereo_20Hz.launch file can not run and error is:

... logging to /home/zahra/.ros/log/709c28dc-a145-11e7-8f93-c8600022c399/roslaunch-zahra-9839.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

unused args [rgbd] for include of [/opt/ros/indigo/share/rtabmap_ros/launch/rtabmap.launch]
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

please help me!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271541/rtabmap-with-stereovision/) by [zahra.zahra](https://answers.ros.org/users/32018/zahra.zahra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2017-09-26**:
Can you post the log file it refers to. it should be located in the .ros/logs folder in your home directory

**Comment by [psammut](https://answers.ros.org/users/31213/psammut/) on 2017-09-26**:
Also, can you describe your setup more? What stereo camera are you using? Can you get the stereo camera to just publish images correctly? If you are using a rosbag, can you get that to play through the images correctly on its own?

**Comment by [zahra.zahra](https://answers.ros.org/users/32018/zahra.zahra/) on 2017-09-26**:
i am using zip file from rtabmap site that is content left and right images (stereo_20Hz.zip). i am following tutorials of rtabmap and useing file from this site.

**Comment by [zahra.zahra](https://answers.ros.org/users/32018/zahra.zahra/) on 2017-09-26**:
i don't know whats happen the rtabmap ros work correctly for rgbdmap but don't work for stereomapping!

**Comment by [zahra.zahra](https://answers.ros.org/users/32018/zahra.zahra/) on 2017-09-26**:
how can see log file?

**Comment by [zahra.zahra](https://answers.ros.org/users/32018/zahra.zahra/) on 2017-09-26**:
i access to log file from terminal with this command:
zahra@zahra:~$ cd ~/.ros/log
zahra@zahra:~/.ros/log$ ls

is it correct?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-09-26**:
Is it this [tutorial](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Stereo-mapping#process-a-directory-of-stereo-images-in-ros)?

**Comment by [zahra.zahra](https://answers.ros.org/users/32018/zahra.zahra/) on 2017-09-27**:
hello matlabbe
yes that is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `rgbd` argument error is a bug in the released launch files for Indigo (this is fixed in recent versions). I updated the launch file of the [tutorial](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Stereo-mapping#process-a-directory-of-stereo-images-in-ros) to be compatible with current Indigo release.

You may have better results with Kinetic/Lunar versions though, here is an example of results:
[image: image description]

cheers,

Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zahra.zahra](https://answers.ros.org/users/32018/zahra.zahra/) on 2017-09-28**:
thanks Mathieu. my problem is solved!
also i have one question. how can small 3dmap for show all scene? my 3dmap is very large and don't show all scene.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-09-28**:
Do you mean the 3D map viewport? You can zoom in/out with the mouse wheel.

**Comment by [zahra.zahra](https://answers.ros.org/users/32018/zahra.zahra/) on 2017-09-29**:
thanks Mathieu.